# How to share prototype functions in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I have two functions I'd like to share across multiple AngularJS controllers, but I'm not exactly sure how to do this for prototype functions.

Previously, the functions were defined right in the controller:

```
Array.prototype.contains = function(needle) {

...

}
```

This allowed any array to be chained using the `contains` method.  However, this does not work when placed in a factory since `contains` is undefined for any array outside the service.

```
(function() {

'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('FunctionsFactory', FunctionsFactory);

function FunctionsFactory() {

    return {
        contains: contains,
        exactlyContains: exactlyContains
    };
    ...
```

What is the best way to share these types of functions across multiple AngularJS controllers?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question, but for shared functionality I think best way - put this functionality into separate service and then inject this service into multiple controllers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best place to have such global common functions is Run Blocks. They are the closest thing in Angular to the Main method.

```
    angular.module('myApp',  [])
    .run(function(){
        Array.prototype.contains = function(){
             console.log('array contains');
        };    
    });
```

Run Blocks get executed after the injector is created and are used to kickstart the application.